# How work interactive notifications in uwp apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a file with my reminders from my class. At the right time i have notification. I create notification with NotificationExtension

```
    ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
    {
        Launch = "OrangeReminder",

        Visual = new ToastVisual()
        {
            TitleText = new ToastText()
            {

                Text = "OrangeReminder"
            },

            BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText()
            {
                Text = ""
            },
            BodyTextLine2 = new ToastText()
            {
                Text = ""
            },
        },
        Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
        {
            Buttons =
            {
                new ToastButton("Done", "1")
                {
                    ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
                }
            }
        },

    };
```

And I create Background task

```
namespace BackgroundTasks
{
public sealed class ToastNotificationBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;
        var arguments = details.Argument;
        //???
    }
```

What I do write in Background task, to remove a reminder from my file when button press in notifications? I think I need my Reminder ID? how to get it?

Comment: For the question about getting reminder id, I have posted an answer below. After getting the reminder ID, how to remove a reminder from a file? What does the file mean? Is it a file placed in Local Storage? I am a little curious about this :)

Comment: I have file "AllReminder.json" in file I have Collection. And I'm just load file, load collection and remove it "Remove(GetRemObject).

Comment: I try this
    if (arguments == "1")
            {
                LoadFile();
                DS.AllRem.RemoveAt(1);
            }
But his not work. Notifications does not disappear. And reminder not remove

Comment: So what is the real problem now? :) Is that you still can't get the reminder Id, or you can get the id now, but you can't remove it from json file using DS.AllRem.RemoveAt(reminderID)?

Comment: @JerryLi The real problem is to get to work the button) The first is ID, next is remove) Maybe I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It should work if the Background task get fired when you click the button. It seems that the background task never got fired when you click the button. So make sure you have [registered the background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) properly.

Comment: @JerryLi Everything works except ID. I can't add string reminderID, because "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'GetRem.RemID'" If make it static, then I can not be serialized.

Comment: Seems you encounted a [Compiler Error CS0236](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za.aspx). If you are trying to initialize a variable outside a method, consider performing the initialization inside the class constructor.

Comment: @JerryLi public sealed class GetRem
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        public string ReminderColor = "1";
        public int RemID { get; set; }
        public string ReminderName { get; set; }
        public string ReminderDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReminderDataTime { get; set; }
        public Boolean? ReminderDone = false;
        ...
    }

Comment: With a single class I was not able to reproduce the issue :) So could you share your project or some more sample code which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Of course I can share, but where? I can give you link from OneDrive, it's ok?

Comment: Yes, link from OneDrive is ok :)

Comment: @JerryLi https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A417F38BECDBAD59!333667&authkey=!AND7iObDtrHCN3w&ithint=file%2czip So in GetRem class i have toast button with argument "Hey" for test. And now i want in argument my RemID

Answer (score 0):

> What I do write in Background task, to remove a reminder from my file when button press in notifications? I think I need my Reminder ID? how to get it?

First get your Reminder ID and set it into the **Argument** of the ToastContent:

```
// get your Reminder Id
string reminderID = GetReminderID();

ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
{
    ...
    Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
    {
        Buttons =
        {
            // set your Reminder ID into the Argument to pass it to the background task
            new ToastButton("Done", reminderID)
            {
                ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Then you can get your Reminder Id **in Background task** through the **Argument**:

```
public sealed class ToastNotificationBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;
        //  get your Reminder Id in Background task through the Argument
        var reminderID = details.Argument;
    }
}
```